# Include OpenId in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, openid, drupal-modules

i want to create a OpenId login system like stackoverflow :) in drupal..By default, drupal doesn't offer this..is there any plugin that does this job?

EDIT:the user should **ALSO** be able to login with their yahoo, gmail, aol or blogger account..u guys can't understand my pro..
it's simple..i've openID enabled in my drupal 6. When i try to use my gmail or yahoo account, it doesn't login.

What should i do for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes, there's a module for that.](http://drupal.org/project/openid)

But you added a `drupal-6` tag, which suggests you're using Drupal 6; OpenID [has been a core part of Drupal 6](http://drupal.org/node/152893) for >2 years - it's documented in the [handbook](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/openid).

Comment: ya, but it DOESN'T have an option to login with their gmail or yahoo id like how stackoverflow does

Comment: Those are just special cases: a google user's openid URL is `http://www.google.com/profiles/<<username>>`, for yahoo it's `https://me.yahoo.com/<<username>>`. The specific buttons StackOverflow uses are just javascript shortcuts which act as though the user typed that string in the box and pressed the button.

Comment: Actually, that's only partially true; Google provides another url (`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`) which works for any user regardless of their usename - see `http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html` for more. Yahoo do something similar with `http://yahoo.com/`

Comment: But even if you don't add those shortcuts, users can still log in by providing the specific URLs for their provider.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a module that uses the [Javascript OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) to add a similar visual interface and makes OpenID on Drupal much easier to use, the module is called [OpenID Selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector).

Answer (score 1):

OpenId already included in core in drupal 6, just enable it.
For drupal5 you need to install appropriate module.