# Google Apps OpenID url

Tags: openid, google-apps, google-openid

Problem:

> My organisation, ExampleFooBar, uses Google Apps. On our website I want
>   to enable OpenID Single Sign-In (like StackOverflow), but only allow
>   @examplefoobar.com email addresses to sign in. What OpenID url should I
>   use for a Google Apps email address?

- As per comments on [Include OpenId in drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041561/include-openid-in-drupal), the domain `http://www.google.com/profiles/<username>` can be used for normal Google accounts, but this doesn't work for Google Apps accounts.
- Google also provides the url `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` but using that would allow any google user who found our website's login page to sign in, as the sign-in page accepts any google account name.

What Google URL can I use to ensure only @examplefoobar.com email addresses can sign in?

Google documentation for Google Apps OpenID is at http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html, but is incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: For the record, Google [no longer supports OpenID 2.0 and suggests migrating to OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By aaronsnoswell:

The OpenID url `google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=examplefoobar.com` will restrict email entries to `@examplefoobar.com`. Additionally, I had to enable OpenID Single Sign in from the Google Apps administrator page. Hope this helps someone!

http://jeremiahlee.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-to-setup-openid-with-google-apps/

[Google Apps (for business) OpenID login for ASP.NET intranet site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293752/google-apps-for-business-openid-login-for-asp-net-intranet-site)

Comment: Thanks for posting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The OpenID url https://google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=yourdomain.com will restrict entries to @yourdomain.com. You also need to enable OpenID Single Sign In from the Google Apps admin page at http://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain.com/SetupIdp

You should also add an X-XRDS-Location header on your website at yourdomain.com/openid in the format:

X-XRDS-Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?ns=2&hd=yourdomain.com