# Google OpenId: Accept only users of a particular company

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth, google-openid

I am trying to use open id in my application and I have done it successfully with [DotNetOpenId](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/).

Now, Google provides service for email and others under the domain of the companies. (Like *example@acompany.com*). Is there a way to narrow down the authentication to users of a company only?

I know I can do it simply by checking the email address from the response. But I do not think this is a good idea. Its better if the user is NOT authenticated by Google accounts other than that of *acompany.com*.

Please note that I DONOT know the inside logic of *Open Authentication* or *DotNetOpenId*.

### Edit

By default Google's openId request prompts *`https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?...`*

I can manually change it (in the browser) to *`https://accounts.google.com/a/iit.du.ac.bd/ServiceLogin?...`* and it works (`iit.du.ac.bd` is my school's domain)

I have tried to create request with

```
        Identifier id1 = Identifier.Parse("https://www.google.com/a/iit.du.ac.bd");
        Identifier id2= Identifier.Parse("https://www.google.com/a/iit.du.ac.bd/accounts/o8/id");
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

       IAuthenticationRequest request1 = openid.CreateRequest(id1);
       IAuthenticationRequest request2 = openid.CreateRequest(id2);
```

Google's identifier is `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id"`

### Edit2

Just found [google-apps-openid-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877985/google-apps-openid-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hesitation on using email addresses as your filter is *absolutely correct*.  Follow you instinct. :)

You should filter on OP Endpoint.  This will not only assure you that Google is the Provider, but Google has a dedicated OP Endpoint for each individual domain, so you can check that.

```
IAuthenticationResponse response = relyingParty.GetResponse();
if (response != null) {
    if (response.Provider.Uri.AbsoluteUri == "http://google.com/o8/....?domain=yourcompany.com") {
        // Allow it
    } else {
        // Disallow it
    }
}
```

Something like that.  You'll have to test to see what the actual URI is for the case you're expecting.

Comment: I get the same AbsoluteUri no matter from where I get authenticated. Always `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud`. Is there a way to tell from which specific provider I have to be authenticated. By default, the login page goes to `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin...`. But if I change it to `https://accounts.google.com/a/iit.du.ac.bd/ServiceLogin...`, it works just fine. However, the response is still from just Google. No sign of my company (School actually).

Comment: Hmmm... I thought Google uses a unique OP Endpoint for each domain, along the lines of `https://google.com/accounts/o8/ud?hd=examplefoobar.com`. If not, I don't know of any way to guarantee that the user belongs to the company/school.  Checking the email address is *not* a guarantee regardless, since a normal Google account could probably have that email address listed on the profile, even if the person is not (any longer) affiliated with the company.

Answer (score 2):

To verify the users email address you would have to ask for it as some point. Either ask before authentication or in the DotNetOpenId request. If you're just going to allow `@abcInc.com` address and not anyone else I really don't see the justification for using openId at all. You're better of with the default .net membership provider.

**Edit**: adding the openId code behind

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult openIdLogin(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationRequest aRequest = openid.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(collection["openid_identifier"]));

        string ReturnUrl = Request.Form["ReturnUrl"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl)) {
        aRequest.AddCallbackArguments("ReturnUrl", ReturnUrl);
        }
        var fetch = new FetchRequest();
        fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
        aRequest.AddExtension(fetch);

        return aRequest.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult openIdLogin(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ReturnUrl == null) ReturnUrl = "";

        var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationResponse response = openid.GetResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            switch (response.Status)
            {
                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    ClaimsResponse sreg = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
                    if (sreg != null)
                    {
                        sreg.Email; //do something with the email address

                    }
                   //codez
                break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier", "Login was cancelled at the provider");
                    break;
                case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier", "Login failed using the provided OpenID identifier");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can verify by checking the email. But I do not like the idea. And I am using openId because I do not want to handle credentials my self.

Comment: the out of the box implementation of forms auth is just as easy as DotNetOpenId's. VS will do most of the work for you anyway. As best I know Google doesn't care about your restrictions other then what you can ask (and Google willing to return) about the user. It will still be up to you to verify it

Comment: Its nothing about easy or taught. I am used to deal with Forms Auth. --------And you think that restriction cannot be applied? :(

Comment: I don't understand. New MVC projects created in VS already include account pages, webconfig settings and a `sql` script to run against your database. Either way you must modify the authentication process to verify the email. The advantage of forms auth is that you could do client side validation.

Comment: But with Forms authentication, I will need to verify that the user who is registering is the valid user. Usually which is done by a email verification.

Comment: Also, the users will need to maintain profile for email and my app too. On the other hand, with OpenAuth, I can get the user info from Google.

Comment: Google will only provide **some** profile information. In fact I ended up needing a profile table anyway. If you can get the users name please let me know. I'd be interested in what you get to work. Either way I think you'll have to look at their email address

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13197/discussion-between-mohayemin-and-eonasdan)