# Redmine Google Apps Auto Registration

Tags: openid, redmine, google-apps, auto-registration

I would like to allow my Google Apps users to automatically register to redmine. I found another post that gave me the site url that I can use.

[Google Apps OpenID url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877985/google-apps-openid-url)

google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=examplefoobar.com

Is there a way I can configure redmine to auto register only openid users (google apps) from my domain, examplefoobar.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I did not catch exactly your goal. But you can look at our redmine plugin [redmine_omniauth_google](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_omniauth_google). It allows to login through google and has a way to setup only your domains.

Comment: This is perfect as is doesn't affect users/emails that already exist either.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know mintRedmine the Android for Redmine?

You can manage issues with mintRedmine easily and smartly.
mintRedmine is free and supports almost all the functionality of the Redmine webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [OpenID Fix](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/openid-fix) plugin for this. However this plugin does not support restricting OpenID URLs currently (as well as Redmine itself). So, I guess, you need to customize it...